# Carrierwave: "recreate_versions!" strange behaviour

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I have an `avatar` uploader which has multiple versions. Some of them are generated synchronously on upload, others are generated conditionally on request (following [this approach](http://code.dblock.org/2011/09/22/carrierwave-delayjob-processing-of-selected-versions.html)):

```
user.avatar.is_processing_delayed = true
user.avatar.recreate_versions!(:png_x60y80)
```

I put this code in a controller and serve the generated version from there once, after that it's served by nginx (since it's already generated). This does actually create the file and if I call `user.avatar.png_x60x80.file` on the same uploader instance right after `recreate_versions!` I get a file object. However, if I call it on another instance of the same avatar (e.g. `User.find(user.id).avatar.png_x60x80.file`) I get `nil`. This won't be a issue, but I believe that it causes the following problem: when I remove the user's avatar only versions that were created synchronously are deleted. Somehow `recreare_versions!` does not persist data about recreated versions. Is there something that I'm missing? I would also like to remove all versions that were created on request when avatar is updated, so that nginx wouldn't serve previously generated versions of an old avatar, but it's also problematic due to this problem.

Carrierwave version: 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I settled for the following workaround. Not perfect, but works as expected.

```
mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader

def remove_avatar!(*args)
  remove_all_avatar_versions
  super(*args)
  # Somehow wrapping the "remove_avatar!" method changes its behavior:
  # model attribute is not updated and we have to update it manually.
  write_attribute(:avatar, nil)
end

def avatar=(*args)
  remove_all_avatar_versions
  super(*args)
end

private

def remove_all_avatar_versions
  return unless avatar?

  avatar.versions.each_key do |v|
    # You have to implement the avatar_path method.
    path = avatar_path(v)
    File.delete(path) if File.exist?(path)
  end
end
```